Error: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str in python while inserting data to SQL Server
I am trying to insert data from data frame to SQL Server using below parameterized query where some of the values are of NoneType which making query to failed with the error:

can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str.

This is my code:
for index, row in df.iterrows():

   sqlstring1="INSERT INTO dbo.sample (id,name,branch)       values(?,?,?),"+row.id+","+row.name+","+row.branch

   cursor.execute(sqlstring1)

How to build the query expecting the NoneType as values.

Obviously at least one of  row.id, row.name, row.branch is None. That said - don't construct the INSERT statement manually/concatenating, And by the way, right now what you will get is invalid sql statement.

This question is similar to: How can I insert NULL data into MySQL database with Python?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

That would be the way to do it using parameterized query
sqlstring1="INSERT INTO dbo.sample (id, name, branch) values (?,?,?)"
for index, row in df.iterrows():  
   cursor.execute(sqlstring1, (row.id, row.name, row.branch))

